# using boost::deadlin_timer - timer.expires_at() always bigger than microsec_clock::local_time()

Tags: c++, boost

A simple Loop is supposet to run until a timer expires.
I researched the Topic online and several other questions.
This is my best attempt, unfortunatelly it is always in the expired state.
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace std;

class Timeout
{
private:
    io_service io;
    deadline_timer timer;
public:
    Timeout(int ms) : timer(io)
    {
        auto now = microsec_clock::local_time();
        auto expfromnow = milliseconds(ms);
        timer.expires_from_now(milliseconds(ms));
        io.run();
        auto expire = timer.expires_at();
        cout << "Timeout(int ms)   " << "expire:" << expire << "   now:" << now << "   ms_argument:" << ms << "   expfromnow_argument:" << expfromnow << endl;
    }

    int NotExpired()
    {
        return !Expired();
    }

    int Expired()
    {
        auto expire = timer.expires_at();
        auto now = microsec_clock::local_time();
        int isExpired = (int)(expire < now);
        cout << "Expired()   " << "expire:" << expire << "   now:" << now << "   isExpired:" << isExpired << endl;
        return isExpired;
    }

    ~Timeout()
    {}
};


int main()
{
    int t = 1000;
    cout << "Init " << microsec_clock::local_time() << endl;
    Timeout timeout(t);
    cout << "Loop " << microsec_clock::local_time() << endl;
    while (timeout.NotExpired())
    {
        cout << "Swing " << microsec_clock::local_time() << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(t / 2));
    }
    cout << "End " << microsec_clock::local_time() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can i fix my timeout so that the main function behaves as expected?

The source now Outputs the following:

[image]

I underlined in red what i think is the issue on my machine.
I work on a Windows machine and with a vs2013 Compiler.
My boost is boost_1_59_0.

EDIT #1:
Seeing the comment from @Tanner Sansbury i added some more Outputs to the source in order to Isolate the Problem.

EDIT #2:
I stared at the Output for a bit and i realized that there is a multiple hour difference. My local time is about 12 now... i sit in Germany... i think this may be the issue.

Comment: The Asio deadline timer seems like overkill for a synchronous time check.  Regardless, I cannot duplicate the behavior that the state always returns as expired.  See this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3219cc91a890ab9a).

Comment: @TannerSansbury thanks for the demo. I added a bit more output and included your threadsleep. It seems to me that my implementation concludes 6 is bigger than 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to Switch to universal time. `universal_time` does not depend on your local timezone and `expires_from_now` seems to use universal time too. A good idea if you think about globalization.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace std;

class Timeout
{
private:
    io_service io;
    deadline_timer timer;
public:
    Timeout(int ms) : timer(io)
    {
        auto now = microsec_clock::universal_time();
        auto expfromnow = milliseconds(ms);
        timer.expires_from_now(milliseconds(ms));
        io.run();
        auto expire = timer.expires_at();
        cout << "Timeout(int ms)   " << "expire:" << expire << "   now:" << now << "   ms_argument:" << ms << "   expfromnow_argument:" << expfromnow << endl;
    }

    int NotExpired()
    {
        return !Expired();
    }

    int Expired()
    {
        auto expire = timer.expires_at();
        auto now = microsec_clock::universal_time();
        int isExpired = (int)(expire < now);
        cout << "Expired()   " << "expire:" << expire << "   now:" << now << "   isExpired:" << isExpired << endl;
        return isExpired;
    }

    ~Timeout()
    {}
};


int main()
{
    int t = 1000;
    cout << "Init " << microsec_clock::universal_time() << endl;
    Timeout timeout(t);
    cout << "Loop " << microsec_clock::universal_time() << endl;
    while (timeout.NotExpired())
    {
        cout << "Swing " << microsec_clock::universal_time() << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(t / 3));
    }
    cout << "End " << microsec_clock::universal_time() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]